# How to add bootstrap css and js in apostrophe cms

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

this is my configuration in apostrophe-assets. did i miss something?

```
// This configures the apostrophe-assets module to push a 'site.less'
// stylesheet by default, and to use jQuery 3.x

module.exports = {
  jQuery: 3,
  stylesheets: [
    {
      name: 'bootstrap.min',
      minify: true
    },
    {
      name:'font-awesome.min',
      path: 'fonts/css',
      minify:true
    },
    {
      name: 'style',
      minify: false
    },

    {
        name: 'site'
    }

  ],
  scripts: [
    {
      name: 'jquery-3.2.1.min',
      minify:true
    },{
      name: 'popper'

    },{
      name: 'bootstrap.min'
    },
    {
      name: 'custom'
    },
    {
      name: 'site'
    }
  ]
};
```

i have referred https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/pushing-assets.html. also i have overwrite the existing module in apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to know if its necessary to add `jQuery: 3`

look at my code:

```
lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js
```

```js
module.exports = {
  stylesheets: [
    {
      name: 'site'
    }
  ],
  scripts: [
    {
      name: 'site'
    },
    {
      name: 'lethargy.min'
    },
    {
      name: 'smartscroll.min'
    }
  ]
};
```

my js files are located in the default path like that:

```
lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public/js/lethargy.min.js
```

---

You can push assets as well from every widget here for example in index js of :

```
lib/modules/example-widget/index.js
```

```js
  //Create functions for pushing assets to browser
  afterConstruct: function(self) {
  self.pushAssets();
  },

  //load third party styles and scripts
  //init has all settings for fullpage
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.pushAssets = function() {
      self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'vendor/materialize.min', { when: 'always' });
      self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'overrides', { when: 'always' });
      self.pushAsset('script', 'vendor/materialize', { when: 'always' });
      self.pushAsset('script', 'init', { when: 'always' });
    };
  }
```